# How to hide empty region in Omega

Tags: 7, blocks, theming, debugging

It seems that by default all regions are rendered in Omega theme because of the Debug blocks.

```
<aside class="grid-3 region region-sidebar-first" id="region-sidebar-first">
  <div class="region-inner region-sidebar-first-inner">
    <div class="alpha-debug-block"><h2>Sidebar First</h2><p>This is a debugging block</p>
    </div>  
  </div>
</aside>
```

Is there a way to have an option to debug blocks and hide empty blocks at the same time?

Answer (score 2):

Go to `admin/appearance/settings/your_subtheme_name`. Check attached image. You can set rights on who is or isn't allowed to see debugging stuff.

Uncheck debugging options will hide empty blocks...

[image]

Comment: But this hides debugging option from the user completely. I want to be able to see debugging blocks and hide them completely without going to configs.

Comment: Use roles option. check for "administrator" only...

Comment: yes, but then as administrator I will see the broken page..

Comment: I will vote up the answer as it is helpful, but there is still a problem with the theme as it is not practical to change config all the time. I would rather had this region removed completely when Debug is off in the theme.

Comment: this doesn't make sense. if debug option is checked, then empty block will be shown . thats it.....

Comment: why does it need to show the empty block, sorry I don't get it.

Comment: To use debugging option

Comment: This is inconvenient, cause it breaks layout even when I hide blocks.